# ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder with userTokenCache

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I am unable to use ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder with userTokenCache.

Code in samples look something like this but this code is obsolete now and I am supposed to use ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.

```
ConfidentialClientApplication app;
            var request = httpContext.Request;
            var currentUri = UriHelper.BuildAbsolute(request.Scheme, request.Host, request.PathBase, _azureAdOptions.CallbackPath ?? string.Empty);
            var credential = new ClientCredential(_azureAdOptions.ClientSecret);
            TokenCache userTokenCache = _tokenCacheProvider.GetCache(httpContext, claimsPrincipal, authenticationProperties, signInScheme);
            string authority = $"{_azureAdOptions.Instance}{_azureAdOptions.TenantId}/";
            app = new ConfidentialClientApplication(_azureAdOptions.ClientId, authority, currentUri, credential, userTokenCache, null);
            return app;
```

**ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder Code**

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                       .Create(_azureAdOptions.ClientId)
                       .WithAuthority(authority)
                       .WithRedirectUri(currentUri)
                       .WithCertificate(clientCertificate)
                       .Build();
```

Comment: Have you found an answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

Its done a bit differently now.

You initialize the TokenCache implementation separately and attach it to the app object. see [this line](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/3ba5234b7ff562447badc73de2342ce55b4bfbd6/Microsoft.Identity.Web/TokenAcquisition.cs#L339) for reference.

Its highly recommended you study how the Token Cache is best implemented for MSAL. The [TokenCacheProviders](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/token-cache-serialization) folder has the implementations.

Comment: Could you please fix the TokenCacheProviders Link?